# When to use savepoint = False in django transactions?

Tags: django, database

I can use inner atomic blocks as savepoints and catch inner savepoint errors. This way, we proceed within the atomic outer scope, just rolling back the inner atomic block, as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835309/django-nested-transactions-with-transaction-atomic-seeking-clarificatio), but there is this argument `savepoint=False` that I don't see any use case for.

In the docs:

> You can disable the creation of savepoints for inner blocks by setting the savepoint argument to False. If an exception occurs, Django will perform the rollback when exiting the first parent block with a savepoint if there is one, and the outermost block otherwise. Atomicity is still guaranteed by the outer transaction. This option should only be used if the overhead of savepoints is noticeable. It has the drawback of breaking the error handling described above.

If I understand correctly, it will just change the fact that even catching an error from the inner block, the outer scope will still rollback. Is it correct?